# Android notification whenever new data is added on firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I want to create an app which displays notification whenever new data is added on firebase database.

once i click on notification, that notification should open activity (i.e. events activity) when we click on the notification.

we should be able to get notifications even if app is closed

can anyone help me on this

what should be approch

i m new to android programming

Comment: If you're new to Android programming, this sounds like biting off quite a bit at once. It is definitely too broad to reasonably answer here in Stack Overflow. The best I can recommend is that you follow the [Firebase codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to:

1. Create and start a Service
2. Initialize FirebaseApp on that Service and add a ChildEventListener/ValueEventListener to whatever node you want to listen for a change.
3. Create a Notification when your Data changes and set its Target to your Activity
4. Run that Service on another process so it stays running even if your App is closed.

Edit: This is by no means a resource-friendly way to do it.